# How to use a date into a where clause with nestjs, sequelize and postgresql?

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs

I have my identity with date: Date;
The constructor:

```
@Get('count')
  async countAllForDateAndLocation(@Query('date') date: Date, @Query('location_schedule') location_schedule: string) {
    return this.scheduleService.countAllForDateAndLocation(date, location_schedule);
  }
```

The service:

```
async countAllForDateAndLocation(date: Date, location_schedule: string) {
    await Schedule.findAll({
      where: {
        date: typeof Date,
        location_schedule: location_schedule,
      }
    })
  }
```

i'm passing the following date: 2021-09-18 through insomnia, as follow
http://localhost:3000/schedule/count?date=2021-09-18&location_schedule=S%C3%A3o%20Paulo
and getting the following error
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "location_schedule", "date", "id_users", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Schedules" AS "Schedule" WHERE "Schedule"."date" = 'Invalid date' AND "Schedule"."location_schedule" = 'São Paulo';
[Nest] 1876  - 11/09/2021 10:13:53   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "Invalid date"

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not providing the date itself but rather it's type:

```js
date: typeof Date,
```

Try providing the value instead in `where` object:

```js
await Schedule.findAll({
  where: {
    date: date,
    location_schedule: location_schedule,
  }
})
```

Comment: i did: 
```
date: Date,
```
and
```
await Schedule.findAll({
  where: {
    date,
    location_schedule,,
  }
})
```
server's response:
```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "location_schedule", "date", "id_users", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Schedules" AS "Schedule" WHERE "Schedule"."date" = '2021-09-12 03:00:00.000 +00:00' AND "Schedule"."location_schedule" = 'São Paulo';
```
I've tried:
```
await Schedule.findAll({
  where: {
    date: "2021-09-12",
    location_schedule,
  }
})
```
and server response was the same before... The Date type might be the problem?